# System.NullReferenceException Epplus Opening Worksheet

Tags: epplus

I am using Epplus to try to open and read a spreadsheet -- a regular spreadsheet with four columns in xlsx format.  I run my code, get the Null Reference error, then tell it to resume and the error is gone.  It's like the package isn't fully loaded.  I've tried .Sleep(5000) but that doesn't work.  I've tried it in and out of USING statement.

```
        if (!File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            return;
        }
        ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(FileName)); 
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); <<-- ERROR HERE
```

Any help, advice or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, do not think that we can help without having some info about the file you are loading

Comment: It is a regular Excel spreadsheet

Comment: then why your issue does not happen on my side? is it a huge file? what version of EPPLUS are you using?

Comment: I don't know.  I think my computer is super fast and the file is tiny and the package is still loading when I issue the ws command.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line with the error and inspect the Worksheets collection.  Anything in it?

Comment: It says "NULL"   then when I press F11 again, it loads up.  But it always gives me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this in case anyone else has this problem.  I created a new Excel File and it worked.  I tried it out on a bunch of other files and it worked.

The problem was specific to this file.  I don't know if it was because it had special formatting or several sheets -- whatever it was, a particular Excel file was creating the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think EPPLUS cannot handle .xls (or the old excel type), I resolve mine too, when i save a new copy that has .xlsx file type. and it works!